Electrocuting a worm on slot car track
Something I saw on TV in The Netherlands and stuck to me ever since. It was live action, with the typical older actors playing high school(?) kids. I saw it in or after 1989, as I saw Moontrap earlier and it gave me some bad nightmares, but before 1995. It was in colour. The spoken language was probably English, but might have been Dutch. As I only saw a small fragment, I don't know whether this was a movie or a single episode of a series.
These are the scenes I remember:
A kid, looking like a scientist, built a big machine. Central to it was a segment of slot car/scalextric track with a worm or slug on it. The scientist and some other spectator(s) watched closely as the worm slowly inched it way across the track. When it touched the electrified center rails it disappeared in a flash. The spectators where elated. I vaguely remember someone mention that time travel was involved, but the poor worm might as well just have exploded.
In a different scene, one guy looked out of the window of his house at night. Two persons in white NBC-suits (or spacesuits) where clumsily walking around outside. They weren't supposed to be there, as the guy in the window expressed his surprise by shouting at them. I'm not sure if the suited persons where really using the suits or just dressed up and really drunk.
